# Arabic text replaced with escape sequences when creating CSV files using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a CSV file that contains Arabic tweets collected using tweepy for a project I am doing. All is fine gathering the data, however, when i am writing to the CSV file all Arabic results are escaped with \xXXXX sequences
as follows:

> b'#\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x88\xd9\x85_\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb9\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x85\xd9\x8a_\xd9\x84\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb9\xd8\xa7\xd9\x82\xd9\x87_2017 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xa5\xd8\xb9\xd8\xa7\xd9\x82\xd8\xa9 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xad\xd9\x82\xd9\x8a\xd9\x82\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa9 \xd8\xa7\xd8\xb9\xd8\xa7\xd9\x82\xd8\xa9 \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x81\xd9\x83\xd8\xb1 \xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa \xd8\xa7\xd8\xb9\xd8\xa7\xd9\x82\xd8\xa9

I looked at many previously asked questions and all I could find was suggestions for python 2 or answers similar to the one I am writing. When I was creating JSON files instead I was using `ensure_ascii=False` but I couldn't find anything similar for CSV. Below is my code:

```
 with codecs.open('tweets.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        fieldnames = ['tweet', 'country']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        data = {'tweet': status.text, 'country': status.place.full_name}
        writer.writerow(data)
```

I tried adding `.encoding='utf-8'` to `status.text` and `status.place` as well but that also didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the Arabic string you have is decoded into UTF-8 before you write it. Assuming `status.text` is of type `bytes` you should type `text=status.text.decode('utf-8')`. (Maybe you have to do this for `status.place.full_name` too.) But if it's of type `str` then it won't have an `decode()` method. To avoid escape sequences in your file, a `str` object should be written anyway.

If you try to specify the encoding of a `bytes` object (like the one you presumably have) as 'utf-8' that won't work because the text is already in UTF-8 **bytes**. So in order to get UTF-8 *characters* you must call `decode()` on the `bytes` object. That way it writes the UTF-8 characters and not the UTF-8 bytes.